# Dirvish expire rules doesn't match

Tags: debian, backup

i got a problem with the dirvsh expire rules. It seems that they didn't match at all.

**The situation**

*System*

```
Linux titan 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
dirvish                        1.2.1-1.2
rsync                          3.1.1-3
```

*master.conf*

```
bank:
        /var/backup
exclude:
        /backup/**
        /dev/**
        /proc/**
        /sys/**
        /mnt/**
        /lost+found/**
        /var/tmp/**
        /tmp/**
        /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
        /var/lib/localbackup/**

log:    bzip2
image-default: %Y-%m-%d-%H
Runall:
        server1
expire-default: +6 hours
expire-rule:
hr { 00,01 }    +7 days
wd { mon }      +4 weeks
md { 1 }        +2 months
```

I'm using the Time::Period notation instead of the cronjob notation. See: http://www.dirvish.org/dirvish.conf.5.html Section *EXPIRE RULES*

*/etc/cron.d/dirvish*

```
0 */2 * * * root /etc/dirvish/dirvish-cronjob
```

*/etc/dirvish/dirvish-cronjob*

Actually it's the stock file from the debian package. **I removed the */usr/sbin/dirvish-expire --quiet* to collect all backupsets, so that i can take a look at the expire statement within the summary files.**

```
/usr/sbin/dirvish-runall --quiet
```

**My desired backup retention interval**

- Keep the backup made at 00:00 or 01:00 for 7 days.
- First day of month for 2 months.
- And the backup made on monday for 4 weeks.

**Symptoms**

One backupset called 2015-08-23-00. Which means made at 00:00 (see image-default). This should kept for 7 days but in the summary stands:

```
 Image-now: 2015-08-23 00:44:27
 Expire: +6 hours == 2015-08-23 06:44:27
```

Now another one, made this morning. *2015-08-24-01*

```
 Image-now: 2015-08-24 01:04:56
 Expire: +6 hours == 2015-08-24 07:04:56
```

The setup is quite new, so i don't have any older backupsets to check the 2 month interval.

Any help is appreciated. If you need futher information, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused.  You say that `master.conf` is the default, but that expire syntax doesn't look like any default file I am finding on my Debian 8 system.  I have never seen the syntax you are using  before.  Where did you find that syntax?

Comment: I added additional info about the master.conf and the alternative notation in the expire rules.